# Disjoint $AC$ equivalent to $AC$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I want to show that these two forms of $AC$ are equivalent:

$(1)$ For each collection of nonempty sets $X$ there is a choice function.
$(2)$ For each collection of pairwise disjoint nonempty sets $X$ there is a choice function

$(1) \Rightarrow (2)$ is trivial.
$(2) \Rightarrow (1)$: Let $X=\{X_i: i\in I\}$ be a collection of nonempty sets with index set $I$. Then $X':=\{X_i \times \{i\}:i\in I\}$ is a collection of pairwise disjoint sets. But how can I get a choice function from here? I've read that a set which has exactly one element in common with each element of the collection would be a choice function, but I kinda don't understand why this set can be seen as a function.

Answer (score 5):

Once you have a choice function from $\{X_i\times\{i\}\mid i\in I\}$, meaning some $f$ whose domain is $I$ and $f(i)=\langle x,i\rangle$ where $x\in X_i$, simply take the projection onto the left coordinate, and show that this is a choice function for the original family.

Comment: May I please ask why the $\lbrace X_i×\lbrace i\rbrace∣i∈I\rbrace$ is a set?( in Morse-Kelley set theory).

Comment: And also, may I please ask why we can have is a set contains all the sets in the form above (as we defined)? (Sorry but since my question is closed, I am only allowed to ask here).

Comment: Do you know that MK proves Replacement in its ZF form?

Comment: Sorry I do not know that. If possible, may I ask for a simpler explaination?

Comment: What is your axiomatization of MK? The same as the one on Wikipedia?

Comment: I have edited, see here.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251031/question-of-proving-equivalence-of-axiom-of-choice-in-sf-mk